# Tell if user is using more than one hand

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a Swift application and want to ensure that the user is only ever interacting with the app with one hand, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The device detects *fingers*, not *hands*. If the user used one finger from each hand, the device would have no way of distinguishing this from two fingers of one hand. Similarly, the user could touch sometimes with one hand, sometimes with the other, and the device would not know this.

(If six fingers touched the device at one time, you *might* suspect that the user is using two hands at once!)

Comment: What about telling if the device is being held?

Comment: Only fingers on the screen are detected. The device knows its orientation in space but not _why_ it is oriented that way.